# Nginx with Odoo configuration: host not found in upstream

Tags: nginx, odoo

What should I change in the (almost) default Nginx configuration below to be able to open Odoo at `http://erp.my-odoo.com`, knowing that I've set the DNS `erp.my-odoo.com` pointing to Odoo server at `192.168.0.10` ?

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/odoo.conf`

```
# Odoo Upstreams
upstream odooserver {
    server erp.my-odoo.com:8069;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name erp.my-odoo.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo_error.log;


    # Proxy settings
    proxy_read_timeout 720s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
    proxy_send_timeout 720s;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    # Request for root domain
    location / {
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_pass http://odooserver;
    }

    # Cache static files
    location ~* /web/static/ {
        proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
        proxy_buffering on;
        expires 864000;
        proxy_pass http://odooserver;
    }

    # Gzip
    gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
    gzip on;
}
```

This configuration gives me the error below:

```
$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "erp.my-odoo.com:8069" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/odoo.conf:3
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure host `erp.my-odoo.com` is resolvable by your server running nginx, or if your nginx is running on same server as your Odoo application, you can change upstream into `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

```
upstream odooserver {
  server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
```

Comment: After making this change, Nginx test is passed successfully but when opening the URL `erp.my-odoo.com`, I'm redirected to `http://odooserver/web` which is not resolved `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the nginx configuration, can you add `proxy_mode = True` to odoo config file, restart nginx and Odoo?

Comment: Not sure it's the correct way to solve it, but I replaced `odooserver` by `erp.my-odoo.com` and it's now working.

Comment: Yes, not sure what went wrong with your configuration. You can always skip adding the upstream block and proxy pass to the the Odoo application directly, using `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069;`, using `upstream` block isn't mandatory.